# Speeding Up Macros

Tags: vba

I'm not very experienced with VBA but with some help on SO and plenty of searching I put together this monstrosity

```
Sub All()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim nRows As Integer: nRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim cell As Range, r As Range: Set r = Range("A2:A" & nRows)
Dim r1 As Range: Set r1 = Range("B2:B" & nRows)
Dim Sel As Range

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
Sheets.Add.Name = "Original Report"
ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Module1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete

ActiveSheet.UsedRange. _
SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell). _
EntireRow.Delete

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
Selection.Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:=Chr(32), _
 LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
On Error Resume Next
For Each cell In Intersect(Selection, _
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlTextValues))
    cell.Value = Application.Trim(cell.Value)
Next cell
On Error GoTo 0

Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, "TOTAL"
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With


'Module2
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

For Each cell In r
    If InStr(1, LCase(cell.Value), "customer:") < 1 Then cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1).Value
Next

Columns("I:I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

Columns("B:B").Select
For Each c In Selection.Cells
    If c.Value = vbNullString Then c.Value = 0
Next

For Each cell In r
If InStr(1, LCase(cell.Value), "retenue au projet") > 0 Then
    If Sel Is Nothing Then
        Set Sel = cell
    Else
        Set Sel = Union(Sel, cell)
    End If
End If
Next cell

If Not Sel Is Nothing Then
    With Sel
        .Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Cut
        Sheets.Add.Name = "Temp"
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End With
End If

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy

Worksheets("Temp").Activate
Rows(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete


ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
With ActiveSheet.Sort
.SortFields.Clear
.SortFields.Add Key:=Selection.Columns(1), Order:=xlAscending
.SetRange Selection
.Header = xlYes
.Apply
End With

Range("A1").Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(2), _
Replace:=False, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True

ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 2

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Sheets.Add.Name = "Unbilled Holdbacks"
ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A").Replace _
What:="Total", Replacement:=vbNullString, _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True


'Module3
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select

With ActiveSheet.Sort
.SortFields.Clear
.SortFields.Add Key:=Selection.Columns(1), Order:=xlAscending
.SortFields.Add Key:=Selection.Columns(2), Order:=xlAscending
.SetRange Selection
.Header = xlYes
.Apply
End With

Range("A1").Subtotal GroupBy:=2, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), _
Replace:=False, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True

For Each cell In r
    If InStr(1, LCase(cell.Value), "customer:") < 1 Then cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1).Value
Next

Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 2

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Sheets.Add.Name = "Master"
ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

With ActiveSheet.Sort
.SortFields.Clear
.SortFields.Add Key:=Selection.Columns(2), Order:=xlAscending
.SetRange Selection
.Header = xlYes
.Apply
End With

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("B").Replace _
What:="Total", Replacement:=vbNullString, _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Sheets("Temp").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

I've finished debugging it and it does what I need it to but it takes a while to run. Does anyone have any pointers on making this more stable/efficient? I've tried clearing the clipboard and reducing the amount of selecting (I know there's still a lot but it was much worse) but in some cases it affected the output and I had to keep the .Select. Any advice on what to work on is much appreciated.

Edit: As to the purpose of the code, it is mainly to take a disorganized data dump and format it a very specific way.

Comment: First, break your macro into different subs, where each sub only does one specific task. Do this as much as possible. Make sure that you have every sub commented to explain what it does. Every line which is even slightly confusing / ambigious should be commented with an explanation. You think it was difficult to piece this together - but for you to come back in 6 months and improve it (or for us to try and improve it) it is a lot of different ideas, none of which are clear or connected.

Comment: Fair point, this originally started as several macros that I amalgamated hence the mess. As I'm cleaning up the code I'll be sure to properly annotate it.

Comment: Brandon,  you can also use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ That is may be more suited for this sort of question.

Comment: Okay Matthew, once I finish going over the code again I'll post the result there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code have quite a lot of redundancy. For example:

```
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
```

If you are deleting the first 5 rows can be:

```
Rows("1:5").Delete xlUp
```

Same goes with the *Column* part. You can improve as well if you incorporate *With Clause*.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Rows("1:5").Delete xlUp
End With
```

Now, to help you in coding and make *Intellisense* kick in, set your object in a declared variable.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim r As Range, c As Range

With ws
    .Rows("1:5").Delete xlUp
    .Columns("A:B").Delete xlToLeft
    .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).EntireRow.Delete
    Set r = .UsedRange
    r.Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:=Chr(32), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
    For Each c In Intersect(r, r.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlTextValues))
        c.Value2 = Application.Trim(c.Value2)
    Next

    '.
    '.
    'and the rest of your coding
End With
```

Now, I'm not sure if the *For Loop* is necessary but if you can eliminate that, it may speed things up a bit as well. I have no suggestion for that since I don't know the purpose. I leave it as is.

So in short, tidy up your code a bit. I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Great tips, the multiple rows thing didn't even occur to me haha. I'll give the declared variables a go as well, thanks.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that, for example the Range r can be set to different values in different With clauses?

Comment: @BrandonPatrick Yeah. `r` is a variable of _Range Type_. And so from the word itself _variable_, it can be set and reset anywhere in your code. But make sure you control it and follow your set logic to get the output you expect. Write your code part by part, test it and once they do what you expect it to do, put them together. That way you'll be able to control the flow, execution time and anticipate errors.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing, the code is much more manageable now. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This does not address you code directly but,  try stepping away from it and learning how to use objects with some simple tasks on a blank sheet.  Then you will understand how to apply them to your code.

```
Dim ws as Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Then without even activating it or selecting anything on it, you can do anything such as

Work with Ranges

```
ws.Range("A" & lRow).NumberFormat = "@"
ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value = "SomeText"

if ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value = "somevalue" then
    'Do something
End if
```

Delete rows

```
ws.Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Delete
```

Get the worksheet properties.

```
Dim str As String
str = ws.name
msgbox (str)
```

It pretty much goes

> Application ->    WorkBook ->      Worksheet ->  Any object on a worksheet

Comment: I'll give it a try, it seems I've got a lot more to learn in VBA

Answer (score 1):

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

run macro

Application.ScreenUpdating = true